# AspNetUserRole table creating multiple columns in the database after customizing .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

I am using EF Core 5 and have extended EF Core Identity to manage user auth. But when I migrate my Entity objects to the database it creates extra columns in the database for example:

`AspNetUserRole` table creates 4 columns in the database `UserId` `UserId1` `RoleId` `RoleId1` in the database.

Here are my extended classes to give you more insights:

ASP.NET USER ENTITY:

```
public class AspNetUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public AspNetUser()
        {
            UserRoles = new List<AspNetUserRoles>();
            AspNetUserShippingInfo = new List<AspNetUserShippingInfo>();
            AspNetUserPaymentInfo = new List<AspNetUserPaymentInfo>();

        }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string ExternalUserId { get; set; }
    public string ExternalProviderName { get; set; }
    public bool VerifiedEmail { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Vendor")]
    public int? VendorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Vendor Vendor { get; set; }


    //TODO: remove from here. doesn't belong here maybe
    [ForeignKey("DeliveryCompany")]
    public int? DeliveryCompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual DeliveryCompanies DeliveryCompany { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<AspNetUserShippingInfo> AspNetUserShippingInfo { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<AspNetUserPaymentInfo> AspNetUserPaymentInfo { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<AspNetUserRoles> UserRoles { get; set; }

    public int? PreferredZipCode { get; set; }
    public string PreferredLanuage { get; set; }
}
```

ASP.NET ROLE ENTITY:

```
public class AspNetRoles : IdentityRole<string>
{
    public AspNetRoles()
    {
        UserRoles = new List<AspNetUserRoles>();
    }
    public virtual IList<AspNetUserRoles> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

ASP.NET USER ROLE ENTITY:

```
public class AspNetUserRoles : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public AspNetUserRoles() : base()
    {

    }
    public override string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual AspNetUser User { get; set; }

    public override string RoleId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    public virtual AspNetRoles Role { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong that generates these extra columns in the database. any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following step to solve your issue.

1:change your `AspNetUserRoles`

```
 public class AspNetUserRoles : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public AspNetUserRoles() : base()
    {
    }
    public override string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetUser User { get; set; }
    public override string RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetRoles Role { get; set; }
}
```

2:In your context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AspNetUser, AspNetRoles, string,
    IdentityUserClaim<string>, AspNetUserRoles, IdentityUserLogin<string>,
    IdentityRoleClaim<string>, IdentityUserToken<string>>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        //add this code,do not set a composite primary key.

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUser>(b =>
        {
            b.HasMany(e => e.UserRoles)
                .WithOne(e => e.User)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                .IsRequired();
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetRoles>(b =>
        {
            b.HasMany(e => e.UserRoles)
                .WithOne(e => e.Role)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                .IsRequired();
        });
    }
```

3:Remigration and update database.

Comment: Thanks for helping with that, Can you also explain why EF gets confused?

Comment: Did you use a composite primary key to cause this problem?

Comment: @Yinqiu Could you please take a look at this one:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72183250/asp-net-core-identity-added-extra-foreign-key-in-aspnetuserroles

Answer (score 0):

If You Don't Include This Code Then Your Code Works Fine Your AspNetUserRoles  Class Look Like This

```
public class AspNetUserRoles : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public AspNetUserRoles() : base()
    {
    }    
    [Key]
    public virtual AspNetUser User { get; set; }   
    [Key]
    public virtual AspNetRoles Role { get; set; }
}
```

You Can Also Do Something Like This

```
public class AspNetUser : IdentityUser
    {
    public AspNetUser()
    {
     this.Role=new HashSet<AspNetRoles>();
    }
   public virtual ICollection<AspNetRoles> Role { get; set; }
}
public class AspNetRoles : IdentityRole<string>
{
    public AspNetRoles()
    {
        this.User=new Hashest<AspNetUser>();
    }
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUser> User { get; set; }
}
```

If you Go With Second Option Then You don't Need To add Extra Class AspNetUserRoles for Many To Many Relationship
Just Try This Last code  it working Fine in my computer

```
 public class AspNetRoles
    {
        public string RoleId { get; set; }
        public string USerId { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: I tested your code and it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Can you provide startup class Detail